# How do I uninstall Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse

I just installed Eclipse Mars on my Windows 7 PC using the Eclipse installer, but I don't see an option to uninstall (not the installer, the installation directory, nor *Add/Remove Programs*). I also didn't find any installation log, so I don't know exactly what changed to manually undo. How do I completely remove it from my machine?

Comment: Same problem here. Eclipse Installer created lots of directories here and there and now I'm forced to find and delete them manually. What a crap.

Answer (score 2):

> In general, Eclipse doesn't have a traditional install or uninstall process. It's basically just a folder of the application and then a workspace that you would have selected/created when you first run it.
>   If you used the Eclipse Installer, you may also have a bundle pool folder named .p2 under your user home directory. There can also be .eclipse in your user home. Other than that, there shouldn't be anything Eclipse-related. installation is just removing those folders.
>   What else do you see that seems to be Eclipse-related?

https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1073664/